# Can I add more function keys?

Tags: keyboard

Between Steam, recording software, and the key bindings in my games themselves, I sometimes have more functionality that I would like to bind to hotkeys than I have function keys on my keyboard. I have 12 function keys built into my laptop. Is there some peripheral I can use to add more function keys to bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logitech has the [G13](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g13-advanced-gameboard) which has 25 programmable 'G-keys' which you can bind to any action (even macros).

Answer (score 5):

The best approach would be to simply **rebind some of the commands to include modifiers**. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not a combination most games use, so Steam uses it for their overlay. You can most likely rebind your recording program's "Start recording" command to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Play/Pause</kbd> or something similar.

Since you mention that you're on a laptop, if you are dead set on independent buttons you could remap commands to the numpad keys and **plug in a USB numpad**.

If you want to get *really* fancy, there are technically 24 Function keys: F13-F24 have completely valid scancodes and OS-level API representations. They're rarely included in physical devices, but you could use software like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to **remap keys (or combinations) so they fire F13-F24 instead**.

Answer (score 0):

While browsing Arqade, I stumbled across [GlovePIE](http://glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php), which will let me use my gaming peripherals as additional keys for my laptop as well.

Edit:

Link no longer available. See https://web.archive.org/web/20140507073550/http://glovepie.org:80/lpghjkwer.php for the download links.